# ¿Como corregir la función del checkbox del formulario de contacto?

Tags: javascript, formularios, checkbox

Buenas tengo un formulario que venia por defecto en una pantilla. Yo he creado un checkbox para la política de privacidad.
El problema es que la función creada le bloquea totalmente  hasta que que no se marca la casilla.
Antes de marcarle como disabled, dejaba pinchar y me avisaba que debía de rellenar  los campos vacíos. 
Esta es la función creada para el checkbox la cual he añadido en html pues si la añado en el codigo javascript de la plantilla, me lo rompe:

```
document.getElementById("aceptar_terminos").addEventListener('change', checkAccepted)
function checkAccepted(e) {
  var botonEnviar = document.getElementById("botonEnviar")
  console.log(this.checked)
  var isNotChecked = !this.checked
  botonEnviar.disabled = isNotChecked
}
```

Muestro como tengo el formulario modificado por mi,si pueden guiarme en que debo modificar, para que al intentar enviar desde el botón, me avise que debo marcar la casilla.
Sin esta función, me deja pulsar el botón, aunque no deja enviar si no completo los campos. 
Necesito que no bloquee el envió radicalmente como lo hace ahora.
Se que es porque tengo `disabled`en el `html`, pero si no añado eso, se envía el formulario sin marcar la casilla.
Gracias.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    (function($) {
        "use strict";

    
    $.validator.addMethod('answercheck', function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^\bcat\b$/.test(value);
    }, "type the correct answer -_-");
  
  $('#success,#error').hide();

    // validate contactForm form
    $(function() {
        $('#contactForm').validate({
            rules: {
                name: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                phone: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                subject: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 10
                },
                message: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 20
                }
            },
            messages: {
                name: {
                    required: "Por favor, ingrese su nombre...",
                    minlength: "El nombre debe tener mas caracteres..."
                },
                phone: {
                    required: "Por favor, ingrese su numero de teléfono para contactar...",
                    minlength: "El telefono no es correcto..."
                },
                email: {
                    required: "sin correo electrónico, sin mensaje"
                },
                subject: {
                    required: "Por favor, indique un tema..."
                },
                message: {
                    required: "Debe escribir algo para enviar el formulario",
                    minlength: "¿eso es todo? ¿De Verdad?"
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                    type:"POST",
                    data: $(form).serialize(),
                    url:"contact_process.php",
                    success: function() {
                        $('#contactForm :input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        $('#contactForm').fadeTo( "slow", 0.90, function() {
                            $(this).find(':input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                            $(this).find('label').css('cursor','default');
                            $('#success').fadeIn();
                        });
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        $('#contactForm').fadeTo( "slow", 0.15, function() {
                            $('#error').fadeIn();
                        });
                    }
                })
            }
        })
  
  
        $('#serviceForm').validate({
            rules: {
                name: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                phone: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                selectService: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 1
                }
            },
            messages: {
                name: {
                    required: "come on, you have a name don't you?",
                    minlength: "your name must consist of at least 2 characters"
                },
                phone: {
                    required: "come on, you have a phone don't you?",
                    minlength: "your phone number must consist of at least 2 characters"
                },
                email: {
                    required: "no email, no message"
                },
                selectService: {
                    required: "Select one service"
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                    type:"POST",
                    data: $(form).serialize(),
                    url:"service_request.php",
                    success: function() {
                        $('#serviceForm :input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        $('#serviceForm').fadeTo( "slow", 0.90, function() {
                            $(this).find(':input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                            $(this).find('label').css('cursor','default');
                            $('#success').fadeIn();
                        });
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        $('#serviceForm').fadeTo( "slow", 0.15, function() {
                            $('#error').fadeIn();
                        });
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    })
        
 })(jQuery)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <form id="contactForm" method="post" action="get_in_touch_form.php">
            <div class="messages"></div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Nombre" required="" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" title="Por favor, introduzca un email valido. Gracias...!!"
                    required="" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input id="subject" type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Tema" required="" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <textarea id="message" name="message" type="text" rows="4" placeholder="Mensaje" class="form-control contact_textarea"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
              <input type="checkbox" name="aceptar_terminos" id="aceptar_terminos" value="aceptar_terminos" /> He leído
              y acepto la <a href="politica_privacidad.html" target="_blank">Política de Privacidad</a>
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="submit" disabled id="botonEnviar" value="Enviar..." class="btn submit_now">
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
          <div id="success">
            <p>Su mensaje enviado con éxito.</p>
          </div>
          </div>
          <script type="text/javascript">
          
    document.getElementById("aceptar_terminos").addEventListener('change', checkAccepted)
    function checkAccepted(e) {
      var botonEnviar = document.getElementById("botonEnviar")
      console.log(this.checked)
      var isNotChecked = !this.checked
      botonEnviar.disabled = isNotChecked
    }
  </script>
          </body>
          </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elimina el atributo disabled del botón para que te deje pulsarlo y añade el checkbox a la validación del formulario, igual que estás haciendo con los otros campos. De este modo te dejará hacer click pero te saltará un mensaje que no te dejará continuar (obviamente, añade este atributo también en el objeto de mensajes para que te muestre el mensaje, y en el de server si lo consideras necesario):

```
 $(function() {
        $('#contactForm').validate({
            rules: {
                name: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                phone: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                subject: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 10
                },
                message: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 20
                },
                aceptar_terminos: {
                    required:true
                }
```

Comment: Perfecto, ahora veo lo mucho que me queda por aprender. Gracias @Macaroni

Comment: gracias por contribuir al sitio @Macaroni